# Fourier transform of $H(x-1)/x$

Tags: distribution-theory, fourier-transform

Consider $H(x-1)/x$ as a tempered distribution where $H$ is the Heaviside step function. I want to find an explicit form for its Fourier transform. Any ideas?

Comment: Try expressing it as a Fourier series and integrate term by term.

Comment: I don't see how that would work, it's not periodic or compactly supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\hat f(\nu)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{H(x-1)}{x}\mathrm e^{-i\nu x}\mathrm d x=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm e^{-i\nu x}}{x}\mathrm d x=\Gamma(0,i\nu)=\mathrm E_1(i\nu)=-\mathrm{ci}(\nu)+i\,\mathrm{si}(\nu)
$$
where $\Gamma(a,z)$ is the [Incomplete Gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html), $\mathrm E_1(x)$ is the  [$\mathrm E_n(x)$-Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html) for $n=1$ and $\mathrm{ci}(x)$ and $\mathrm{si}(x)=\mathrm{Si}(x)-\frac{\pi}{2}$ are the [cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html) and [sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html).